# ZFComponent.Initialize is not a function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using EIDA (Emirates Identification Authority) card reader to Read nationality card, Once I insert the card and click on Read Card button i am giving the error message on Mozila.

1. Device driver installed, still getting the same error
2. Java (TM) platform enable on browser

Note: I tried to read a card in another system, card reads properly and not giving any error message, all operation works successfully.

[This image shows the error alert box after click on "Read Card" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4RkZ.jpg)

Comment: cannot help unless you share the html/jsp and javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved !!

Just install jdk 32-bit version, 
I tried with jdk 1.6 32-bit.